# Update Value by AjaxListener

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces, xhtml

my problem is, that I got two fields. Here is the definition:

```
       <h:selectOneMenu id="selectSource" update=":relationTableForm:selectObject" value="#{tabDefineRelationTable.sourceId}" style="width: 100%;" required="true" requiredMessage="Source is required">
                <p:ajax listener="#{tabDefineRelationTable.handleSourceChange}"   /> 
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Source" itemValue="0" noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{tabDefineRelationTable.mySources}"
                    update=":createArtifactForm:selectObject"
                    var="source"
                    itemLabel="#{source.s_name}"
                    itemValue="#{source.s_id}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:selectOneMenu id="selectObject" value="#{tabDefineRelationTable.objectId}" style="width: 100%;" required="true" requiredMessage="Object is required" onchange="submit()">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="first select Source" itemValue="0" noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{tabDefineRelationTable.myObjects}"
                    var="object"
                    itemLabel="#{object.o_name}"
                    itemValue="#{object.o_id}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

I want to implement, if I select in my `selectSource` a field, I update the variable `objectId` in the backend, and see it in my frontend.

Here is my first try to implement it:
Variable definition

```
private List<Source> mySources;
private List<Objects> myObjects;
private Integer sourceId = 0;
private Integer objectId = 0;
```

Constructor:

```
public TabDefineRelationTable (TabLoader parent, List<Source> sources, List<Objects> objects) {
    parentForm = parent;

    mySources = sources;
    myObjects = objects;
}
```

Listener:

```
public void handleSourceChange() {
    this.objectId = 0;
    if (sourceId != 0) {
        for (Source curSource : mySources) {
            if (curSource.getS_id() == sourceId) {
                myObjects.clear();
                myObjects.addAll(curSource.getObjects());
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Best regards
Björn

**Update 1:**
After I tried the solution to use `<p:ajax event="select" update="tabView:relationTableForm:selectObject" listener="#{tabDefineRelationTable.handleSourceChange}"   />`,

`<p:ajax event="select" update=":relationTableForm:selectObject" listener="#{tabDefineRelationTable.handleSourceChange}"   />` or

`<p:ajax event="select" update=":selectObject" listener="#{tabDefineRelationTable.handleSourceChange}"   />`.

I got this errormessage:`Cannot find component with identifier "tabView:relationTableForm:selectObject" referenced from tabView:relationTableForm:selectSource".`

Any other Ideas?

**Update 2:**
`update="@([id$=output])"` testet this one. Didn't got an error, but the field is also not updated :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the ajax line into 
`<p:ajax update="selectObject" listener="#{tabDefineRelationTable.handleSourceChange}"   />`

Big thanks to serdar for help!

Answer (score 1):

could you try this..

```
 <p:ajax update="selectObject" listener="#{tabDefineRelationTable.handleSourceChange}"   />
```

Comment: what is the error ? is it about event ? you can delete event and try after.

Comment: putting the error up into the main posting, you could see it in Update 1.

Comment: if you send full of this xhtml form i can help you, serdarekici2@gmail.com

Comment: Can you try update="selectObject" and delete event="select" .